# Natbib insert period inside parenthetic citation

Tags: natbib, punctuation

On the project that I am working is a convention that the period comes inside the parenthetic citation.

I am using the `natbib` package and do not want to change it because I am just putting the finishing marks on the long project. Changing it now would be too arduous.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}

\begin{document}


\section{Introduction}

Long paragraph ending with a citation \citep{greenwade93}.

\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like the period to be inside the parantheses I.E.

Long paragraph ending with a citation (Greenwade, 1993.)

I know one solution would be to configure the *setcitestyle*, but I suspect this will not do for me because I don't always want to add period inside the citation, only when a period follows the citation.

Comment: IMO it would be wrong to write `Long paragraph ending with a citation (Greenwade, 1993.)`, that period ends the entire sentence and thus belongs outside the parantheses.

Comment: I totally agree with you. However,  this is a convention that I was asked to follow specifically. @daleif

Comment: Then I would ask them to reconsider, this is wrong. If it was `sentence. (other sentence.)` then I agree the last `.` goes inside, but this is not the case here. I've never before seen such an absurd requirement.

Comment: Okay, I might consider putting my neck out for this. Could you, for future reference, show how to insert a period inside the citation, such as the example that you provided?

Comment: Nope, I have no idea how you would get a citation to do that oher than by hand

Answer (score 1):

For the rare cases in which you need the trick, you might do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Doe05,
  author       = "Doe, J. and Other, X.",
  title        = "An interesting title",
  journal      = "A well regarded journal",
  volume       = "163",
  year         = "2005",
  pages        = "287--337",
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Long paragraph ending with a citation 
\citetext{\citealp{Doe05}.}

\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\end{document}
```

Make a command if the cases are not that rare.

[image]